# Strange Processing.dxf issue

Tags: java, processing, dxf

I have been tried to study this [code](http://kylejanzen.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/3d-spectrogram-with-processing-and-microphone/) , everything was fine until I press R to save the dxf output down.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.mode.java.runner.Runner.findException(Runner.java:926)
    at processing.mode.java.runner.Runner.reportException(Runner.java:871)
    at processing.mode.java.runner.Runner.exceptionEvent(Runner.java:797)
    at processing.mode.java.runner.Runner$2.run(Runner.java:686)
```

It appears errors as below

I thought it was the code problem until I tried the very basic SimpleExport sample in the processing dfx library.
The same error popup and the sketch played is not responding. Besides,a file is also written to disk, but is empty.

Any ideas?

***UPDATE: I am using processing 2.1.1, tested in 32bit and 64bit ver

Comment: According to one of the comments to the post you linked to you should try Processing 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues with Processing 2.0 and DXF [a couple of years ago](https://vimeo.com/36354854) and whipped out a basic DXF writing function. Here's the same approach used on the code you linked to:

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

//audio
Minim minim;
AudioInput microphone;
FFT fftLog;
//audio-driven mesh
Waveform audio3D;
//DXF output
boolean record;
PrintWriter out;

void setup()
{
  size(1250,750,P3D); //screen proportions
  noStroke();
  minim = new Minim(this);
  microphone = minim.getLineIn(Minim.STEREO, 4096);

  background(255);

  fftLog = new FFT(microphone.bufferSize(),microphone.sampleRate());
  fftLog.logAverages(1,2);  //adjust numbers to adjust spacing;
  float w = float (width/fftLog.avgSize());
  float x = w;
  float y = 0;
  float z = 50;
  float radius = 10;
  audio3D = new Waveform(x,y,z,radius);
}
void draw()
{
  background(0);
  directionalLight(126,126,126,sin(radians(frameCount)),cos(radians(frameCount)),1);
  ambientLight(102,102,102);

  if (frameCount>200)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < fftLog.avgSize(); i++){
      float zoom = 1;
      float jitter = (fftLog.getAvg(i)*2);
      //println(jitter);
      PVector foc = new PVector(audio3D.x+jitter, audio3D.y+jitter, 0);
      PVector cam = new PVector(zoom, zoom, -zoom);
      camera(foc.x+cam.x+50,foc.y+cam.y+50,foc.z+cam.z,foc.x,foc.y,foc.z,0,0,1);
    }
  }
  //update FFT
  fftLog.forward(microphone.mix);
  //update 3D mesh
  audio3D.update();
  audio3D.textdraw();
  audio3D.plotTrace();
}
void stop(){
  microphone.close();
  minim.stop();
  super.stop();
}
class Waveform
{
  float x,y,z;
  float radius;

  PVector[] pts = new PVector[fftLog.avgSize()];

  PVector[] trace = new PVector[0];

  Waveform(float incomingX, float incomingY, float incomingZ, float incomingRadius)
  {
    x = incomingX;
    y = incomingY;
    z = incomingZ;
    radius = incomingRadius;
  }
  void update()
  {
    plot();
  }
  void plot()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < fftLog.avgSize(); i++)
    {
      int w = int(width/fftLog.avgSize());

      x = i*w;
      y = frameCount*5;
      z = height/4-fftLog.getAvg(i)*4; //change multiplier to reduces height default '10'

      stroke(0);
      point(x, y, z);
      pts[i] = new PVector(x, y, z);
      //increase size of array trace by length+1
      trace = (PVector[]) expand(trace, trace.length+1);
      //always get the next to last
      trace[trace.length-1] = new PVector(pts[i].x, pts[i].y, pts[i].z);
    }
  }
  void textdraw()
  {
    for(int i =0; i<fftLog.avgSize(); i++){
      pushMatrix();
      translate(pts[i].x, pts[i].y, pts[i].z);
      rotateY(PI/2);
      rotateZ(PI/2);

      fill(255,200);
      text(round(fftLog.getAvg(i)*100),0,0,0);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
  void plotTrace()
  {
    stroke(255,80);
    int inc = fftLog.avgSize();

    if(record){//init dxf writing
      out = createWriter("output.dxf");
      out.println("0");
      out.println("SECTION");
      out.println("2");
      out.println("ENTITIES");
    }

    for(int i=1; i<trace.length-inc; i++)
    {
      if(i%inc != 0)
      {
        beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        float value = (trace[i].z*100);
        float m = map(value, -500, 20000, 0, 255);
        fill(m*2, 125, -m*2, 140);
        vertex(trace[i].x, trace[i].y, trace[i].z);
        vertex(trace[i-1].x, trace[i-1].y, trace[i-1].z);
        vertex(trace[i+inc].x, trace[i+inc].y, trace[i+inc].z);
        vertex(trace[i-1+inc].x, trace[i-1+inc].y, trace[i-1+inc].z);
        endShape(CLOSE);

        if(record){//write each quad face to DXF file


          out.println("  0 ");
          out.println("3DFACE");
          out.println(" 10");   // first x
          out.println(trace[i].x);
          out.println(" 20 ");  // first y
          out.println(trace[i].y);
          out.println(" 30 ");  // first z
          out.println(trace[i].z);
          out.println(" 11");   // second x
          out.println(trace[i-1].x);
          out.println(" 21 ");  // second y
          out.println(trace[i-1].y);
          out.println(" 31 ");  // second z
          out.println(trace[i-1].z);
          out.println(" 12");   // third x
          out.println(trace[i-1+inc].x);
          out.println(" 22 ");  // third y
          out.println(trace[i-1+inc].y);
          out.println(" 32 ");  // third z
          out.println(trace[i-1+inc].z);
          out.println(" 13");   // fourth x
          out.println(trace[i+inc].x);
          out.println(" 23 ");  // fourth y
          out.println(trace[i+inc].y);
          out.println(" 33 ");  // fourth z
          out.println(trace[i+inc].z);


        }

      }
    }

      if(record)//finish writing
      {

        out.println("  0 ");
        out.println("ENDSEC");
        out.println("  0");
        out.println("EOF");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        record = false;
        println("wrote DXF!");
      }

  }
}
void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == 'r') record = true;
}
```

It's not super pretty, so feel free to encapsulate the functionality if you want, but it's not too bad either (it's still ASCII, human readable).

Here's a preview from Rhino (after rotating the mesh because Processing's coordinate system isn't the same):

[image: DXF Mesh Rhino preview]